# WDS and DHCP on different server to provide pxe boot

Tags: pxe-boot, dhcp-server, wds

I have two standalone windows server 2016 which configured with WDS and DHCP respectively, and they are located in the same VLAN broadcast domain. I want them to provide PXE boot for client machines to load ESXi image and the client machine is located under the same VLAN broadcast domain too.

the DHCP server is configured with scope option 66(IP address of WDS server) and 67(the boot file path set to "boot\x64\wdsnbp.com" which the ESXi image files are located in), and is activated apparently.

On the WDS server, I set the boot property with "Always continue the PXE boot", the DHCP property without selecting the two boxes (since the DHCP service is located on another server), and ensured that the WDS is running.

However, no matter i chose legacy or UEFI on a client server to boot from network, it was unable to obtain IP and boot file therefore the pxe boot failed.

I place the extracted ESXi image files to the path E:\RemoteInstall\Boot\x64\esxi67u3 and ofcourse installed the syslinux with some configurations beforehand.

I would like to know if I missed something on the WDS or DHCP server?
Can anyone help?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to PXE boot but the client is not getting an IP address?

Comment: yes, my client can't get any ip address to do the pxe boot, sorry for the vague description.

Comment: Can anything else get an IP address from the server?

Comment: i created VM under this broadcast domain and the VM's OS can get the IP from dhcp.